# Another Boolean problem with sculpt addon and union

Tags: modifiers

I had the horns and the head as separated objects and to union them i used a boolean modifier. The problem now is that as you can see in the image there are holes after i smoothed it in the sculpting mode. I used dyntopo which you can also see in the picture. In short the boolean could not union these objects without holes.

[image: Problem]

Comment: Please read the following link: [Boolean Modifier not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92555/boolean-union-of-objects-does-not-work) If the problem persists please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information

Comment: I edited it and i hope that helpt. Of cause i first looked at Google or here to find a solution but there wasnt one.. Like i said i removed the double, looked at the normals and also closed  the Horns to have a manifold object.

Comment: i could include the .blend file but These are quite complex objects.

Comment: <<When i now press Union in the sculpt addon(which just performs a boolean)>>... btw what is the sculpt addon? Imho there's no way to understand based just on above images what's happening, and since you're using way high detailed meshes here... this adds to the complexity to even understand. Can't you simplify a bit the model leaving just the intersecting part as it is, and share it?

Comment: Sculpt addon performs a boolean modifier in just one click by selecting two objects. Two objects horn and head unify with a boolean does not work correctly. After i smoothed it in sculpt mode it showed holes at the seam.